# Unsupported format or combination of formats (Input sample must have 32fC1 type) in cvPreparePredictData

Tags: c++, opencv

I try to train my own SVM to detect person, I resize the sequence of images all to 320x240. I convert images to gray while the training process, while I test I convert the test image to gray but I got an error.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    String folder = "output/*.jpg";
    vector<String> filenames;
    glob(folder, filenames);

    Mat gray,gray1;

    int img_area=320*240;
    Mat training_mat(filenames.size(),img_area,CV_32FC1);
    Mat labels(filenames.size(),1,CV_32FC1);

    for(int i = 0; i < 900; i++){
        labels.at<float>(i,0)=1;
    }
    for(int i = 900; i < filenames.size(); i++){
        labels.at<float>(i,0)=-1;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < filenames.size(); ++i){
        Mat img = imread(filenames[i]);
        cvtColor(img, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
        int ii = 0; 
        for (int k = 0; k < gray.rows; k++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gray.cols; j++) {
                training_mat.at<float>(i,ii++) = gray.at<uchar>(k,j);
            }
        }
    }

    CvSVMParams params;
    params.svm_type = CvSVM::C_SVC;
    params.kernel_type = CvSVM::POLY;
    params.gamma = 3;
    params.degree = 3;
    CvSVM svm;
    svm.train(training_mat, labels, Mat(), Mat(), params);
    svm.save("svm_filename"); // saving
    svm.load("svm_filename"); // loading
    Mat image = imread("output/500.jpg");
    cvtColor(image, gray1, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    int response = svm.predict(gray1);

    if(response == 1){
        cout << "person " << endl ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compile the program I got this error:

> OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (Input sample must have 32fC1 type) in cvPreparePredictData, file /home/mourad/opencv/opencv-2.4.10/modules/ml/src/inner_functions.cpp, line 1102 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert `gray1` to `32FC1` too.

```
cvtColor(image, gray1, CV_RGB2GRAY);
gray1.convertTo(gray1, CV_32FC1, 1.0/255.0); // <-- add this line before predict
int response = svm.predict(gray1);
```

Also, be aware that code below is not the correct way to convert from `uchar` to `float`, since they are expected to work with different ranges: `[0,255]` and `[0,1]`.

```
training_mat.at<float>(i,ii++) = gray.at<uchar>(k,j);
```

Comment: :I added it I got this error:Incorrect size of input array (Input sample must be 1-dimensional vector) in cvPreparePredictData

Comment: How can I convert a 2d image to 1D image?

Comment: @para you should use `reshape` for that. `cv::Mat gray_reshaped = gray1.reshape(1,1);` should do that. Upvote or mark as answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my program :

```
cvtColor(image,gray1, CV_RGB2GRAY);
Mat image_mat(1,img_area,CV_32FC1);
int jj=0;
for (int k = 0; k < gray1.rows; k++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < gray1.cols; j++) {

        image_mat.at<float>(0,jj++) = gray.at<uchar>(k,j);
        }
    }

int response=svm.predict(image_mat);
if(response == 1){

    cout << "person detected" << endl;
}
```

But the program run and didn't display anything.

Comment: Please, posting an answer isn't the correct way to update your question. Delete it and add the new problem to your question without removing any previous information. Also, if it is a completely new problem, the correct action is to ask another question.